# Transfer the Multipart Upload stream down the S3 bucket async using the latest Spring Boot 3.0.x DataBuffer

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, amazon-s3, streaming, multipartform-data

I'm struggling to save the uploaded file on AWS S3 bucket.

Using the latest Spring Boot 3.0.x `DataBuffer` feature I'm handling the `Flux` of `PartEvent`s:

https://github.com/engilyin/useful-articles/blob/feature/%23183953976-s3-attachment-storage/backend/src/main/java/com/engilyin/usefularticles/services/sys/MultipartUploadService.java

```java
public <T extends MultipartDataAccumulator<?>> Mono<T> loadData(Flux<PartEvent> rawPartEvents, T accumulator) {
        return rawPartEvents.windowUntil(PartEvent::isLast)
                .concatMap(p -> p.switchOnFirst((signal, partEvents) -> handlePart(signal, partEvents, accumulator)))
                .then(Mono.just(accumulator));
    }

    private Publisher<PartEvent> handlePart(Signal<? extends PartEvent> signal,
            Flux<PartEvent> partEvents,
            MultipartDataAccumulator<?> accumulator) {
        if (signal.hasValue()) {
            PartEvent event = signal.get();
            if (event instanceof FormPartEvent formEvent) {
                accumulator.pushField(formEvent.name(), formEvent.value());
                return Mono.empty();
            } else if (event instanceof FilePartEvent fileEvent) {
                log.debug("!!! FilePartEvent!");
                String filename = accumulator.generateFilename(fileEvent.filename());
                long fileSize = accumulator.attachmentSize();
                return attachmentService.save(filename, fileSize, partEvents.map(PartEvent::content))
                        .then(Mono.empty());
            } else {
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Unexpected event: " + event));
            }
        } else {
            return partEvents; // either complete or error signal
        }
    }
```

And it works well for local file storage:
https://github.com/engilyin/useful-articles/blob/feature/%23183953976-s3-attachment-storage/backend/src/main/java/com/engilyin/usefularticles/services/storage/LocalFileAttachmentService.java

However it fails to upload onto the `S3` storage:
https://github.com/engilyin/useful-articles/blob/feature/%23183953976-s3-attachment-storage/backend/src/main/java/com/engilyin/usefularticles/services/storage/S3AttachmentService.java

and

https://github.com/engilyin/useful-articles/blob/feature/%23183953976-s3-attachment-storage/backend/src/main/java/com/engilyin/usefularticles/services/storage/S3Service.java

```java
 public Mono<Boolean> save(String filename, long contentLength, Flux<DataBuffer> contentBuffers) {

        Flux<ByteBuffer> buffers = Flux.from(contentBuffers.map(db -> {
            log.debug("Next part: {}", db);
            var buf = db.toByteBuffer();
            DataBufferUtils.release(db);
           // DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer();
            return buf;
        }));

        return s3Service.uploadBuffers(attachmentConfigProperties.getBucketName(), filename, contentLength, buffers);
    }

    public Mono<Boolean> uploadBuffers(String bucketName,
            String objectKey,
            long contentLength,
            Flux<ByteBuffer> buffers) {
        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = s3AsyncClient.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .contentLength(contentLength)
                .key(objectKey)
                //.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.toString())
                .build(), AsyncRequestBody.fromPublisher(buffers));

        return Mono.fromFuture(future).doOnError(this::handleError).map(this::checkResult);
    }
```

I tried similar approach within some Integration JUnit test and it works just fine:
https://github.com/engilyin/useful-articles/blob/feature/%23183953976-s3-attachment-storage/backend/src/integration-test/java/com/engilyin/usefularticles/s3/S3Test.java

It seems like for some reason `s3AsyncClient` can't start pumping the data and `} else if (event instanceof FilePartEvent fileEvent) {` happens multiple times due to errors recognized on by `s3AsyncClient` to start handling the data from the stream.

PLEASE NOTE: it MUST not buffer whole file data, store it on the disk etc.

Would appreciate any help and ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Tried to separate out the buffers flow into separate `Flux` and that helped to succeed with actual operation but that separate `Flux` makes `S3` async client fail with the same error but just ones.

`Sinks.Many<ByteBuffer> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
   s3Service.uploadBuffers(attachmentConfigProperties.getBucketName(), filename, contentLength, sink.asFlux()).subscribe();`
Look like something wrong with buffers or its availability.

Comment: Also I found that subscription at the `s3AsyncClient` actually happens just after all buffers were posted onto the `Flux` and my handler completed with all its operations including adding the new record into the Db.

Comment: What I found us that buffers even does not being touched. That happened at the attempt to initiate the connection with error: `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.` I tested it with multipart upload so there are nothing than bucket name and key. And creds looks good. The same code just works from JUnit test.

Comment: My guess was something wrong with sign. So I tried to make it use v4: `.overrideConfiguration(cfg -> cfg.signer(Aws4Signer.create()))` That changed the error to: `Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256 (Service: S3, Status Code: 400`